# How to pass the Local file path for css/js file in jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery.
In my application i am using checkbox.for a check box i am using the css file url as follows:

now the problem is if the internet is not available then checkbox style(normal image and selected image)is not coming.

so i create one file named with "jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" by copying data from https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css.

i am replacing the above url with my file as follows :

but checkbox styles(normal image and selected image) are not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Your local adressess should look like this:

```
file:///android_asset/www/your_file
```

I am assuming that you are using asset/www folder, or building your app with PhoneGap. Try adding your CSS file like this:

If you want your app to work offline you should remember to add:

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Remember to place your files in asset/www folder, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: i am using the asset/www.i am replacing  "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>" with "<script src="js/jquery.min.js">
        </script>".but it is not working..even i replace with " <script src="file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.min.js">
        </script>",then also no effet(i am putting script tag in "" bcz if i put directly it is not comming in question.)

Comment: Is your file in asset/www or asset/www/js?

Comment: css files are in assert/www/css,js files in assert/www/js

Comment: then place all files in assets/www and try if that works. If so, place them back and manipulate with paths.